# Extending classes in PHP

Tags: php

When extending classes in Java, class name ambiguity is avoided by the usage of qualified package names in the import statements.

For example: Say I want my controller to extend Spring's MultiActionController -  I'll import the same from the standard Spring package. This also prevents me from extending Mike's or Perry's MultiActionController, since I have not imported MultiActionController from their packages.

Similarly in PHP, say we have 10 classes in 10 different library folders, all of which are called MultiActionController.

When I write:

```
class MyController extends MultiActionController {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

How do I tell PHP which MultiActionController (from which folder), to extend from?

Comment: Is there a reason why your limited to PHP4? If your using PHP5, and version 5.3 or better, you will get much better examples with name spaces.

Comment: Am not. SO automatically put that, I don't know why. I'm on PHP 5.2.8 (that's what my host is offering).

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the "php4" tag, and replace it by "php5", so things are clear :-)

Answer (score 7):

Having several classes with the same name will, one day or another, cause some problems : you cannot include two classes with the same name during the execution of one script -- It'll get you a Fatal Error.

What's generally done, in PHP *(before PHP 5.3 and namespaces, at least)* is to include the name of the library and/or the "package" in the class name.

For instance, you could have a class name `MyLibrary_Package_MultiActionController`, and another called `OtherLib_Blah_MultiActionController`.

Then, what's generally done is using that class name to "map" it to directories and files, replacing the '`_`' by '`/`', and adding `.php` at the end of the last level -- this being often done using the [autoloading feature of PHP][1], to avoid having to write an enormous amount of [`require`][2] directives.

For instance, a class named `MyLibrary_Package_MultiActionController` should be stored in `MyLibrary/Package/MultiActionController.php`.

As a sidenote : you used the tag "php4", in your question... If you are actually using PHP 4, you should not forget that it's old, not maintained anymore *(Not even for security-related problems)*, and that PHP 5 is really the way to go !

In fact, you won't be able to do much about object-oriented programming, with PHP 4 ; the object-oriented stuff in PHP 4 was really basic...

*(Stuff such as autoloading, which I wrote about a couple of paragraph earlier didn't exists in PHP 4 -- same for `public`/`private`/`protected`, and lots of other OO-related things...)*

Comment: Thx for the response. I'm on PHP 5.2.8 (see my reply above).

Answer (score 2):

It depends which one you include.  PHP will not let you redefine a class of the same name, so just include above the class definition (change to fit the file names and your software layout):

```
include('../includes/Spring/MultiActionController.php');

class MyController extends MultiActionController {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what a moron I've been. ;)

Answer (score 1):

PHP will extend the class that you included with an include statement.

For example, say that you have a class foo declared in file bar.php:

```
class Foo {
    // methods and fields
}
```

Then in another fie:

```
include 'bar.php';
class Aardvark extends Foo {
    // this class will extend the class Foo in file bar.php
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what a moron I've been.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the file holding the class, with a banal `include()` statement:

```
include('lib/controllers/MultiAction.php');
```

Then you can extend it!

Comment: Thanks, what a moron I've been.

Comment: Everyone needs to learn! By the way, you should read about the difference between `include()`, `require()` and `require_once()`!

include() will throw a non-fatal error if php file missing, require() act the same way but with a fatal error, and require_once avoids the php file to be recalled multiple times from different scripts! Can check here => http://it.php.net/require_once

Answer (score 1):

I would use namaspaces

```
namespace package_products_multicontroller {
include("/packages/products/multicontroller.php");
}

class MyController extends package_products_multicontroller\MultiActionController {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the clearest (read: 'most unambiguous') way (although a bit verbose, if I may dare say that).